# How to set some columns as left justifying in the Tktable?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is it possible to set some columns as left justifying? for example:

```
package require Tktable
table .table -rows 3 -cols 4 -titlerows 1 -titlecols 1
global TableValue
array set TableValue {0,1 Title 0,2 Center_X 0,3 Width_X 1,0 1 2,0 2 \
1,1 test1 1,2 0.5 1,3 0.2 2,1 test2 2,2 0.8 2,3 0.3}
.table configure -variable TableValue
pack .table
```

if I just want to set "Center_X" and "Width_X" as left justifying, how to do it?
I've tried ".table conifgure -anchor w", that makes all the columns left justifying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use tags for that. in your example

```
.table tag col left 2 3
```

adds the specified tag `left` to the columns 2 and 3 (`Center_X` and `Width_X`). Then

```
.table tag configure left -anchor w
```

left-justifies them. If you want the titles to be centered, add

```
.table tag configure title -anchor c
```

(`title` is a predefined tag for title cells).